# Angular2 Material change font-color of md-datepicker

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Im using the datepicker component from the Angular2 Material Framework. Now in my case I have to implement a feature where I have to "mark" certain days in the calender if a certain condition is met. I literally want to change the font-color of the day-number-label where you can click on to select the date. I have tried it with css(look for the right class with the chrome-developer-tool in the DOM) and applied my style but this does only work in the styles.css(located in the same folder as index.html) and not in the css-file attached to the component that contains the datepicker.

BTW: I tried it with the class "mat-calendar-body-cell-content". I applied this style:

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
     color: red !important;
}
```

Is there anyone with a working solution/workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the css you have tried in the question?

Comment: @Nehal I added it